# Symfony 4 - correct Semantic UI integration

Tags: symfony4, semantic-ui

I want to integrate Semantic UI in my Symfony 4.3 project.
I installed with npm:

> npm install semantic-ui --save

But is it correct to build the Semantic folder in the root of the Symfony project?

```
/semantic (default)
```

Or must I go to the `node_modules` semantic folder and run gulp build there? Is there help for me how to implement correct in Symfony?

THX
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to build all assets: javascripts, stylesheets, images etc… bundle together and put inside the `public/` directory (in `public/build` or `public/assets` etc…).

For that you need Webpack, it's currently the best bundler out there. The Encore project integrates this very well with Symfony. Check out the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) on how to manage assets in a Symfony project.

After the deployment on the production, the `node_modules` directory on the remote server can be safely removed to free up the disk space.

Regarding wiring everything together, create a `front` directory in the main app. There create your application, eg. `app.js` in which you load all your javascript files, the Semantic, etc… Using Encore:

```
Encore
  .setOutputPath('public/build/')
  .setPublicPath('/build')
  .addEntry('app', './front/app')
  // more skipped for brevity
```

when you build the project, is going to be emitted to the `public/build` directory by the Webpack.

In your `base-template.html.twig` including the css is as simple as putting:

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
```

in the `head` section and:

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

just before closing `body`.

Should you have any questions regarding [webpack-encore](/questions/tagged/webpack-encore) feel free to post another question. Good luck.

Comment: thx i understand the webpack-encore. But still not sure where to put the semantic folder. So i guess i don't create the standard in the root. I have to create in my public folder, or better in my new Symfony version in my /assets/ folder? And then i include them with webpack, correct?

Comment: I understand all the points. What i still not understand: If i install semantic, i get the folder in my node_modules - and than i use webpack with the config:     // add semantic-ui entries
    .addEntry('semantic_styles', './node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css')
    .addEntry('semantic_javascripts', './node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js') / So i dont need to build it with gulp as a separate folder in my assets? Because it runs like this? Or is there a reason to build it separate in assets and link webpack to this assets folder instead of the node_modules folder?

Comment: You are supposed to build Semantic by yourself. Don't use their entries, use your own. Gulp sucks, maybe use [semantic-ui-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-sass) instead? However AFAICT [Semantic sucks big time](https://medium.com/@naomiHauret/i-used-semantic-ui-as-a-css-framework-and-regret-my-choice-aa4449ab6107). Who uses gulp these days ;)

Comment: I mean it works, was only not sure if this is the correct way.

Comment: Well you are supposed to create your own app, not use Semantic only. Are you not going to add any scripts of yours? Don't go creating another entrypoint for that.